# (Minecraft Forge) Dependency throwing InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have been attempting to create an addon mod for The Lord of the Rings Mod, and I have run into this problem:

```
[17:33:54] [main/ERROR]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicated LocalVariableTable attribute entry for 'this' in class file net/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182) ~[launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:72) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 8 more
```

I do not exactly know what is wrong, but I believe it is nothing I am doing. 
    When I use the mapping `stable_12`, it lasts for a bit longer, then gives me this:

```
[17:44:24] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Fatal errors were detected during the transition from CONSTRUCTING to PREINITIALIZATION. Loading cannot continue
[17:44:24] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: 
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
    UC  mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
    UC  FML{7.10.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar) 
    UC  Forge{10.13.4.1614} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar) 
    UE  lotr{Beta v33.3 for Minecraft 1.7.10} [The Lord of the Rings Mod] ([1.7.10] LOTRMod B33.3.jar) 
    UC  mymod{1.0} [My Mod] (modid-1.0.jar) 
[17:44:24] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: The following problems were captured during this phase
[17:44:24] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Caught exception from lotr
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71410_x()Lnet/minecraft/client/Minecraft;
    at lotr.client.render.LOTRRenderPlayer.<init>(LOTRRenderPlayer.java:28) ~[%5b1.7.10%5d%20LOTRMod%20B33.3.jar:?]
    at lotr.client.LOTRClientProxy.<clinit>(LOTRClientProxy.java:67) ~[%5b1.7.10%5d%20LOTRMod%20B33.3.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:59) ~[forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:512) ~[forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212) ~[forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190) ~[forgeSrc-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275) ~[guava-17.0.jar:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119) [LoadController.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:513) [Loader.class:?]
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:208) [FMLClientHandler.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:523) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:943) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source) [start/:?]
[17:44:24] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.client.Minecraft:displayCrashReport:389]: ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// My bad.

Time: 7/28/17 5:44 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

cpw.mods.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71410_x()Lnet/minecraft/client/Minecraft;
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.transition(LoadController.java:163)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:544)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:208)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:523)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:943)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(Unknown Source)
    at GradleStart.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71410_x()Lnet/minecraft/client/Minecraft;
    at lotr.client.render.LOTRRenderPlayer.<init>(LOTRRenderPlayer.java:28)
    at lotr.client.LOTRClientProxy.<clinit>(LOTRClientProxy.java:67)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:59)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:512)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:212)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:119)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:513)
    ... 12 more
```

My dependency works perfectly at my normal usage, but, for some reason,  here, it just crashes. Nothing is wrong with my actual code, but I think something may be wrong with the mappings or something similar.

Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?